# Connect GitLab registry to ECS on AWS - took too long to respond

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, gitlab, amazon-ecs

I have a python app which I run locally using docker-compose.
I have 2 different docker compose files; one for local development (with node.js and webpack installed) and one for production which just has python and nginx. The one for production is simply called `docker-compose.yml`.

It looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ANALYTICME_NGINX_PROD
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    environment:
      - SETTINGS=PROD
    build: .
    container_name: ANALYTICME_DJANGO_PROD
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn analyticme.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
```

My nginx conf file looks like this:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

This runs well on my localhost, then I use:

```
docker login registry.gitlab.com
docker-compose build -t registry.gitlab.com/[user]/[repo] .
docker push registry.gitlab.com/[user]/[repo]
```

to push the new image to my gitlab registy.

Then I created a new ecs cluster connected to this repo, I haven't really touched any settings when creating the cluster... 
The app gets deployed but when I visit the IP I get: `took too long to respond.`

My task looks like this:

[image: task]

How can I connect the two? Which settings should I change in the cluster to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is very likely due to only having 10 CPU units.

As a comparison - a single core should equal 1024 units; so you're essentially only allowing the container a max of .09% of a core; so it's likely just unable to ever start appropriately.

If this had anything to do with your Gitlab registry, I would expect the task to actually fail as it wouldn't be able to pull in the image.